# force:package:version:promote in CI script not finding package Alias: Subscriber Package Version Id not defined in sfdx-project.json

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, continuous-integration, github, github-actions

I am in the process of creating a CI script that uses GitHub actions for the creation and promotion of new package versions.

For this I have created a shell script that is run after test classes have run and been uploaded to codecov. In there, I reference the node_modules I installed to run sfdx scripts and set environment variables for package numbers and version Ids.

To truncate to the most important part, this is where my script fails:

```sh
# Create a new package version (with the previously incremented package version) and import the package version id for further use.
echo "Creating new package version"
node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:package:version:create -p $PACKAGE_ID -f config/project-scratch-def.json -x -v devhub -c --json -w 30 > result.json

cat result.json
cat result.json | jq '.result.SubscriberPackageVersionId' > packgeversionid.txt

PACKAGEVERSIONID=$( cat packgeversionid.txt )
if [[ "$PACKAGEVERSIONID" == "null" ]]; then    
    echo "Package could not be created"
    exit 1
fi

echo "New Package Version Id: $PACKAGEVERSIONID"

sleep 5
cat sfdx-project.json

#This promotes the package version
echo "Promoting Package Version"
node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:package:version:promote -p $PACKAGEVERSIONID --noprompt -v devhub
```

I am able to create a package version just fine. I am `cat`ing the result just to ensure that everything works the way I expect it to, and the same goes for the `sfdx-project.json`

When I get to the `force:package:version:promote` part, I am running into this error however:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:promote:  The Subscriber Package Version Id or Package Version Id: "04t<>" isn't defined in the sfdx-project.json. Add it to the packageDirectories section and add the alias to packageAliases with its 04t or 05i ID.
```

And that although I verified just beforehand that the exact same `04t` Id is present in the local sfdx-project.json file.

What steps do I need to take to finish the promotion process?

Comment: I wonder if this might be a race condition somehow? What if you increase sleep from 5 to 60 or so? Does that make it work?

Comment: @sfdcfox can it be a race condition when my `cat` output clearly shows me the new package version Id, already after 5 seconds of sleep?

Comment: @sfdcfox That's actually the reason I use `cat` right before my promotion call. And in the Console Output I see in GitHub I see everything I need

Comment: I was more thinking "what if the Id isn't actually available on the server", though I've never seen this, just trying to rule out possibilities.

Comment: Are you sure the sfdx-project.json is well formed and correctly structured?

Comment: Picking up on @sfdcfox's comment, are you sure you run both commands with the same user against the same dev hub?

Comment: The sfdx-project.json is automatically appended by the CLI, which couldn't have worked if it was malformed I wager. I specify the dev hub explicitly with `-v devhub` in both calls

Comment: And I have exactly one action in the pipeline that authenticates me via auth_url, so different users seems to be out of the question too

Comment: Sleep for a minute also doesn't solve the problem, and so doesn't calling sfdx directly without referencing node_modules (switched that due to the colors.js fiasco) @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the retrieval of the Subscriber package version Id.

```
cat result.json | jq '.result.SubscriberPackageVersionId' > packgeversionid.txt
```

Retrieves the value behind the Key including the double quotes.
What is actually necessary (and something I actually did elsewhere in the script beforehand... duh) is use `jq -r` to cut away the quotes.

`sfdx force:package:version:promote` doesn't want you to use double quotes when specifying the package version, so the output that actually **included** these quotes was not part of the Standard Error message, but part of my input, simply interpreted the wrong way.